# How extract text from PDF including images and text

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining, text-extraction

I am going to extract text from multiple PDF files. The PDF files include text and some images and even some pages are scanned pages (I assumed the scanned pages are like images). I followed the below commands to extract text from PDF files. My problem is how I can edit my commands with a condition to check if each page contains any images, then extract text from images.  I would appreciate it if you could help me.

```
lst_all_text = []

for foldername,subfolders,files in os.walk(r"C:/MY PATH"):
    for file in files:
        # open the pdf file
        object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(os.path.join(foldername,file))
        # get number of pages
        NumPages = object.getNumPages()
        text =  ""
        # extract text and do the search
        for i in range(0, NumPages):         
            PageObj = object.getPage(i)
            text += PageObj.extractText() 
            
        lst_all_text.append(text)
```

Comment: See the docs for pypdf2.  But note that (IIRC) pypdf2 is pretty unmaintained.  I think there's now a pypdf4 which is still being maintained

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have done this, so I will put here the general method I have followed:

1. Use the [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#extracting-fonts-and-images) library to handle the pdf files, it extracts the text as well as images from the PDF files.
2. After you have extracted text from file, store the names of the extracted images in a list and the images in one directory.
3. Now, to extract text from images use [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) library. This is an open source library for OCR. Loop over the images from the list and use tesseract to extract the text from the images.

**Note:** The problem I faced with tesseract was that it became really slow as the number of images increased.

Comment: Many thanks, I need to insert the whole extracted text of each PDF file in a list for further analysis.  I mean each member of my final list must include the text of each PDF file. In your approach, I won't miss the order of text for each PDF as images are saved in a separate folder and then probably in another function their text is going to extract. And possibility the extracted text from images would be added to the end of each text extracted from PDF!!!

Comment: @Tahi Hello. I am trying to do the same task where the PDF file contains both extractable text and text in images which require Pytesseract. I am wondering how you are able to solve this problem. I don't want to mix the order of pdf file.